# Maintain some changes on git merge

Tags: git, github, merge, branch, git-merge

I'm a bit confused about a git mechanics.

My work has 3 branches `master` `devel` and `public`. I use `master` for deploy my Node.js app into OpenShift (or heroku); `devel` is where i develope my feature and i use `public` for push my open source code on GitHub.

Everytime i have to deploy my app on OpenShift i just merge from `devel` to `master`and then push.
Same for git, i marge from `devel` to `public`

**Problem is**: example. i have a file, `index.html` in witch there is a snippet of code for private Google analytics. Or ex. i need some files for deployment in `master` but not in `public`

**Question is**: how can i keep this snippet of code and files in `master` but not in `public`?

I thought about 2 (non working) strategies:

1) Snippet\files are not present in `devel` but are present in `master`  --> i merge `devel` in `master` --> snippet\files are deleted from master

In this manner i'm fine with `public` (because will not include the private snippet\files) but i'm not fine with `master`

2) Snippet\files are present in `devel` -> if i merge `devel` to `master` i'm fine with my deploy on OpenShift because the snippet\files are included.

but merging `devel` in `public` --> now `public` has my private files.

Gitignore file can't help me, because are shared between branches and if i ignore my private files they will be ignored in my `master` deploy too. And even so this will not resolve the snippets problem.

**TL.TR**. How can i merge 2 branches keeping some file\part of codes unmerged? Possibly in a simple way, because i have to do this for a lot of file.

Or, how can i change my branch strategies for achieve this?

Comment: I think i reached the solution. Was a mistake in use the git system. `devel` initially had the seme code\files used in the deploy of `master`. Now, deleting these information for clean `devel` branch, mergin in `master` would delete this information too. The solution (is pretty stupid ok i know) is rewrite the files and usefull snippets in `master`. Till now, even if this informations are no more present in `devel`, master will continues to have them even if merge from `devel`. I'm new to git and i was a bit confused :) I just thought the snippets\file would be always deleted with merging!

Answer (score 1):

I found a website that knows how to do this. You can use `excludesfile` for different branches.

Here's how to do it:

```
$ git branch public_viewing
$ cd .git
$ touch info/exclude_from_public_viewing
$ echo "path/to/secret/file" > info/exclude_from_public_viewing
```

Then edit the .git/config file and add:

```
[core]
excludefile = +info/exclude

[branch "public_viewing"]
excludefile = +info/exclude_from_public_viewing
```

Using this approach everything all the public files are in `info/exclude_from_public_viewing` and the personal in `info/exclude`.

The website can be found here: http://cogniton-mind.tumblr.com/post/1423976659/howto-gitignore-for-different-branches

Comment: I found this method time ago in another post but seems not to work (maybe version problem, the post is dated 2010). The problem is, even if this work (will be nice anyway) will not resolve the problem totally because i wanna update my index.html (not ignore it) just leaving some part of code immune on merging. But really thanks anyway, appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

You can change your branch strategy to achieve this. I am assuming that all of you public code should also be present in your master branch.

You can have 4 branches (instead of 3) eg. `master, dev-master, public and devel`

- You should do most of the development(except private files) on `devel` branch and merge it to `dev-master` and `public` whenever you want to. Since it doesn't have any private file, it would not be merged to `public` branch.
- When you want to write your private code, just switch you branch from `devel` to `dev-master` before start writing your private code and then test your feature here. Once everything is correct, merge `dev-master` to `mater` branch.

With this strategy, you can also test your code with/without private files which would be helpful in maintaining the code base.

I am not sure if this is the best strategy. I hope this helps you !!!

Comment: Your branches strategy is very good and i'm switching to your advice right now! This is actually good for better divide the code base from the production part. But i think i found the solution to my problem, was just a mistake in using the git rm and commit. I will explain it better under my first post (maybe for someone will be usefull)

Comment: Forgot to thanks you so much for the advice, apreciated

Comment: I am glad that it helped you in deciding your branch strategy. Please mark this answer as accepted :)